# Jollyday API - How do I create a HolidayManager instance from a URL?

Tags: java

**Quick Introduction:**
For those who don't know; [Jollyday](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday) is an API to help you handle holiday-aware code. It allows you to retrieve public holidays from pre-built configurations. You can even **create your own Holiday Configuration in an XML file** and load it into the API, which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

---

I have **created my own** holiday configuration in an XML file and I want to load it into Jollyday.

The [Official Jollyday Documentation](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/usage.html) *(for version 0.5.1)* **shows an example** of this being done with the following code...

```
URL url = new URL("file:some/path/MyHolidays.xml");
HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(url);
```

### The Problem

When I try to use this code, it will not compile because the `HolidayManager` class **does not have** a `getInstance(URL)` method.

Here is a screenshot of all the overloaded variations of `HolidayManager.getInstance()` *(as seen from IntelliJ IDEA)*.

[image: Screenshot of intelliJ showing all of the HolidayManager.getInstance method variations]

The documentation *appears* to be incorrect.

### Further Information

> "Are you using the correct version of the API?"

Yes, I am using **version 0.5.1** which I downloaded with gradle. This is the same version as was used in the [documentation](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/usage.html).

### The Question

*Is it possible to create a HolidayManager instance using a URL?*
If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a HolidayManager instance using a URL?

- Yes, but the URL has to be wrapped in a [ManagerParameter](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jollyday/ManagerParameter.java) first.

> The documentation appears to be incorrect.

- The documentation became slightly outdated when the code migrated from [SourceForge](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/) to [GitHub](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday) in late 2011.
- If you look at the [GitHub Commit History](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/commits/master/src/main/java/de/jollyday/HolidayManager.java) of `HolidayManager`, you can see that the `HolidayManager.getInstance(URL)` method was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/commit/46d73f22330753cfc39388b8e00f8c74bc6c0a0d).

### Working Example

```
URL url = new URL("file:some/path/MyHolidays.xml");
UrlManagerParameter urlManParam = new UrlManagerParameter(url, new Properties());
HolidayManager holidayManager = HolidayManager.getInstance(urlManParam);
```

This will work exactly as you expected, it just takes a few extra lines. *You should use nicer variable names too, I just wanted to keep it short.*

Don't forget to import the following classes:

```
import de.jollyday.HolidayManager;
import de.jollyday.parameter.UrlManagerParameter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
```

You can now load Custom Holiday Configurations into Jollyday. Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any helper method to get the list of countries whose holidays are configured in xml ? @byxor